# How to convert a function written using Rx Observable.FromEventPattern for event handlers to a pure .net event handler(without Rx)

Tags: c#, event-handling, system.reactive

I have a code snippet that someone has written using Rx in C# that uses Observable.FromEventPattern for event handling.

Here's the existing code that I have which uses Rx

```
private void RegisterToDigitFocusEvents(int index, TextBox digit)
{
    Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventHandler, RoutedEventArgs>(
        h => digit.GotFocus += h,
        h => digit.GotFocus -= h)
        .SubscribeToElement(digit,
            _ => this.ResetDigit(digit, index),
            error => this.Log().Error("Observing digit GotFocus", error),
            () =>
            {
                /* Do nothing on complete */
            });
}
```

I am not allowed to use Rx in my project. I looked up the documentation for FromEventPattern, I was unable to clearly understand what is the pure .Net equivalent of writing the same code without Rx

Here's my attempted conversion which as you might know didn't work quite as expected

```
//Global index so that it can be used across functions
int index1;

private void RegisterToDigitFocusEvents(int index, TextBox digit)
{
    digit.GotFocus += digit_GotFocus;
    index1 = index;
}

void digit_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ResetDigit(sender as TextBox, index1);
}
```

As you notice I haven't written code to unregister the event handler. I am not sure where to put the logic.

I am a beginner to Rx. 
Just to be clear - I do not want re implement the whole observable pattern that Rx provides me, I just want to write a function equivalent of the first snippet without using Rx, pure .Net events.
Any help to write the first code snippet in this post without Rx would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If your purpose is to learn Rx, it's unclear how what you are doing here will help. I am going to vote to close because there appears to be a gap in your understanding that isn't going to be best addressed by attempting to answer your question - although I admit I find the question little unclear anyway. I recommend perhaps starting with the materials located here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx Start with the Curing your asynchronous blues Tech Ed session, and then perhaps work through the Hands On Labs on the beginner page.

Comment: Certainly, learning Rx by reimplementing it yourself would be a very painful strategy. It's open source and a brief look at the code should convince you of this pretty quickly. See the tag wiki for details on where to find it. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/system.reactive/info

Comment: @JamesWorld - Sorry for being unclear in my post earlier. My purpose is not to learn Rx. I am not trying to re implement Rx either by thinking about observable, subscription model. I am just trying to convert a function that somebody has written in Rx in a non-Rx(normal .Net) way because I am not allowed to use Rx in my project. My question is if I didn't use Rx at all what what would be the code equivalent that I would write for the first snippet (which is currently in Rx). Hope I was clear, and can edit the original question if necessary.

Comment: Where does the `SubscribeToElement` method come from? Is it your customer extension method?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is the pure equivalent:

```
    private void RegisterToDigitFocusEvents(int index, TextBox digit)
    {
        RoutedEventHandler gotFocusHandler = (s, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                this.ResetDigit(digit, index)
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                this.Log().Error("Observing digit GotFocus", error);
            }
        };

        digit.GotFocus += gotFocusHandler;
    }
```

You really should extend this code to handle the detaching of the handler when your form closes, but the above should be the basics required.

Please let me know if I've misunderstood the question.